# I posted a pokemon at one gym and did not collect any pokecoins

Tags: pokemon-go

Can someone explain this to me? I have one pokemon placed at a gymn and I collected the 10 pokecoins immediately.  When I placed another pokemon at another gym, I was not able to collect any pokecoins because it has not been 21 hours yet.  However, my two pokemons were defeated shortly after I placed them at the gyms.

Does that mean, in order to collect for the 2nd pokemon, I must be able to hang in that gym for more than 21 hours?

So I tried a second strategy - placed the pokemon first and then collect later, hoping that within 21 hours I can place several pokemons at different gyms.  No such luck. My first one was again defeated within hours and I never got to collect anything.

So how do you collect defend bonus for more than one pokemon at a time?

Thanks.

Comment: Or just don't immediately collect coins the second you place the first one?

Comment: @Ellesedil I don't believe this is a question of how to collect the bonus and more of about strategy of how to keep multiple Pokémon in gyms to collect larger bonuses each time.

Comment: @Virusbomb: Yes, I agree. I've already retracted my flag.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, make sure you understand how claiming the defender bonus works. For this, please see [this answer on How Do I Collect My Defender Bonus?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/284018/68492).

To answer your more specific question of how to claim multiple bonuses, in order to be able to claim your bonus for multiple gyms, you need to wait on claiming the bonus until you have taken over all of the gyms you are hoping to hold. Of course, this is a multiplayer game, so there is some risk involved in delaying when you claim the bonus. While you're busy taking that third gym down the street, someone else could be trying to capture one of the gyms you're currently controlling.

Once you decide that you are done trying to take additional gyms, you should then claim the bonus. This will then put your defender bonus on the 21 hour cooldown, and you'll be unable to claim any additional bonuses for that length of time. In the event that you control, for example, 3 gyms when you claim the defender bonus, you'll receive 30 coins and 1,500 dust and must wait 21 hours before claiming it again.

Also see [this accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281131/68492) which is similar to what you are asking.